# What is an environment vector?

Tags: c++, vector, environment

I am writing a short program that displays the argument count (argc), argument vector(argv[]), and environment vector. However, I am unsure how to display the "environment vector" or what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: I've been using C++ since about the time it was invented, and I've never heard of the environment vector. If this is a school assignment (and I don't see how it could be anything else) you should consult your notes/textbook/instructor.

Comment: I suspect (confirmation needed) that this refers to an extension: `int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp);`

Comment: Your title does not correspond to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "environment" parameter, traditionally named `envp`, is a zero-terminated array of `char*`.

You can display it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
{
    while (*envp)
    {
        std::cout << *envp << std::endl;
        envp++;
    }
}
```

It's not part of POSIX (or any other standard) but supported by many compilers.